# How to change option in CMakeLists.txt by calling cmake with special arguments

Tags: cmake

I have some complicated CMake project containing an option like:

```
option(BUILD_WITH_FEATURE  OFF)
```

This option is scattered in many CMakeLists.txt and I really don't want to change all the files manually, as I often need to switch between ON and OFF.

Can I call cmake with some parameters like

```
cmake --setOption  BUILD_WITH_FEATURE=<ON|OFF>
```

, so that the option is changed consistently among all CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill in options by passing the following to your cmake command: `-DOPTION=VALUE`.

So in your case you will have to use: `cmake -DBUILD_WITH_FEATURE=ON`.

Clearing your CMake cache before may be needed (CMakeCache.txt).

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. I'll check it with my project.